# export inkscape image for work in Finale Cut Pro

Tags: inkscape

how do i export an .svg file in Inkscape so that when i import the .png image into Finale Cut Pro, it doesn't look grainy?  the image in the video doesn't need to be super-high definition; just something a little better than i'm currently getting.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You say are exporting an SVG, but importing a PNG into other software. What are you using to create the PNG? Aren't you exporting the PNG from Inkscape? PNG images exported directly from Inkscape shouldn't be grainy.

Comment: sorry, ya, i'm taking a .svg file and exporting it to .png within Inkscape.  when i import the .png file, it appears graining — not terribly so, but i was hoping for a little bit better clarity in the image.

Comment: Is the PNG grainy when exported from Inkscape? I can't reproduce the problem. Can you share the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Grainy" is a very specific adjective, which I think will not apply on a SVG image exported.

You probably are seeing pixelation or saw edges.

In any case, simply export to the exact size you need or as a bigger image.

[image]

In order to have a higher resolution as default, you can simply leave the DPI number higher than the actual number. If it is set to 72dpi you can put 150, or whatever number you need. This depends on how the SVG was originally made.

Comment: ok, that makes sense.  is there a way to set the default export image size in Inkscape?  i have about 1000 images, and i don't want to set the image size for each one.

Comment: I added new info on the anaswer.